Why d orbitals oriented along $z^2$ axis assigned zero magnetic quantum number?
I have been studying quantum mechanics recently and I have come across this:

d orbitals oriented along the $z^2$ axis is assigned zero magnetic quantum number

I am wondering why specifically the $dz^2$ orbital has zero magnetic number. I am thinking if this is just randomly chosen for reference or if it has any specific purpose.I had tried to find out the answer by using many logics like , plotting the orbital in the graph . But I can't get the correct logic behind this.
Kindly help me around this statement to find the correct logic. Thank you for spending your valuable time.

Convention. They are all degenerate eigenfunctions, so any linear combination may be taken and they can point in any direction you want. It's just the standard convention is, as you say, to have the one with m=0 along the z axis.

They are named after their behavior in a static B-field in z-direction, which would lift the degeneracy of these orbitals. The energy of the z^2 m=0 orbital does not change in such a field, hence the zero quantum number. The  other orbitals do change in energy proportional to their magnetic quantum number.

The $3d_{z^2}$ orbital, also known as the $3d_0$ orbital, does not have assigned a magnetic quantum number $m_l$. It is the solution of the Schrödinger equation with $n = 3, l = 2, m_l = 0$. If you remember, the solutions of the Schrödinger equation are eigenfunctions of the $\hat{L}_z$ operator with an eigenvalue $m_l\hbar$, and thus
\begin{equation}
  \hat{L}_z\psi_{3,2,0} = (0)\hbar = 0 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
When you see orbitals with the subscripts "$x^2 - y^2$" or "$xz^2$", they are not the original solutions of the Schrödinger equation. They are linear combinations of some of the solutions in order the give rise to real hydrogenlike orbitals, i.e. new wavefunctions which have the same energy as the orbitals which were combined, but they are real functions (and not complex functions).
The $3d_{z^2}$ orbital happens to be 'no linear combination', it is just the $3d_0$ orbital. The reason why the $z^2$ is there, is because the Cartesian component $z^2$ pops up when you write the full wavefunction, i.e. you read the term $r^2\cos^2\theta$.
You asked for a 'purpose' of choosing that as a reference. As we saw, there is no 'reference' selected. However, I would like to give some explanation of what $m_l = 0$ means:

You have an electron in a certain region of space. As to have a sense of where it can be, I plot below three spherical harmonics with the same magnetic quantum number $m_l = 0$.

The electron will be found in that region of space (with some probability) with a magnitude of the angular momentum equal to $L = \sqrt{l(l + 1)}\hbar$.
Since $L_z = 0$, then that vector $\mathbf{L}$ has no projection onto the $z$ axis. It would be some vector which is parallel with the $xy$-plane.
However, since $\hat{L}_x$ and $\hat{L}_y$ do not commute with $\hat{L}_z$, we do not know the $x$- and $y$- components of the angular momentum. We just know the length of the vector and that it is parallel to the $xy$-plane.

This reasoning applies to all the electrons which are in the orbitals with $m_l = 0$. The only difference is that the region of space where the electron can be found is larger (see how the $x$, $y$, and $z$ scales get bigger in the graphs), because the electron has more energy and can be found farther away from the origin. More formally, the electron has more energy to penetrate through regions of space where the potential energy is higher.
Maybe the label $z^2$ or $z^3$ makes more sense with this graphs. The region of space where the electron can be found is centered around the $z$ axis as two opposing lobes separated by planes where there is zero probability of finding the electron.

References

Introduction to Quantum Mechanics with applications to Chemistry, Linus Pauling and E. Bright Wilson, Jr., McGraw-Hill Book Company, 1935.

